# How do I pull data from 2 rows where the data is not the same?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns AZ and BA.  I want to pull all of the data for the rows where for each row AZ and BA are not the same.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I am new to EXCEL.  I'd imagine something along the lines of:

```
AZ != BA
```

Comment: Excel has `if` statements

Comment: I assume you you want AZ1 <> BA1; and AZ2 <> BA2; etc... rather than BA1 is not in any row in AZ?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, next to BA1 you can put `=IF(BA1=AZ1,"",BA1&" "&AZ1)`

Then drag it down. This will display a combination of all non-matches.

I mean you could also do `=IF(BA1<>AZ1,BA1&" "&AZ1)` as well.

This is an [IF function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx). Syntax:

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

Comment: Slightly different output format, which will make it slightly easier if you want to filter on that cell, and only show the ones that don't match `=IF(BA1<>AZ1,"Not a Match","Matched")`